# MyImagePicker from WWDC 2010 sample code displays nothing

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, assetslibrary

I compiled and ran the MyImagePicker project from the [WWDC 2010 sample code](http://bit.ly/cEf0rM) on my iPhone 3Gs with iOS 4.2.1, but it just gives me a blank table.  Shouldn't it be populating with data from my photo roll?

Interestingly, I also get a blank table in the [UIImagePickerController Clone from iCodeBlog](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController).

Both of these projects apparently use the AssetsLibrary framework -- what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have assumed that the picker would automatically select from the saved photos album.

Change the following line in RootViewController.m from:

```
NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces;
```

to:

```
NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;
```

to just get saved photos...  It turns out that this isn't any better for my purposes than the stock UIImagePickerController, but it was a learning experience.